# nginx default catch all configuration

Tags: nginx

We are using nginx to serve static content and apache for dynamic content.

I have defined a default server configuration as:

```
#Set a default server that simply proxies all requests to apache
server 
{
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / 
    {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Is the the best way to proxy everything to apache if for some reason a server_name does not match?

Comment: I do not get your question, this is a copy-paste from the nginx wiki. Are you asking whether the nginx wiki is correct? Erm, yes, it is...

Comment: What I am asking is, if I want to proxy all requests to apache, is this the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the best and the only sensible way. You could even omit the servername completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSL, then you need some extra plumbing for a default_server - certificate and key (that can be self-signed).

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate <path to cert>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;
    location / 
    {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Nginx will try to accept SSL connection on an IP/port-matching default_server. If such server is missing cert/key, nginx will drop the connection. It won't try other servers. So don't forget cert/key.